# How do I display the results of console.log in JS Fiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

Using JS Fiddle how do I display the result of `console.log`. I'm teaching a class, for free, and I'd like to give me students a place where they can go and run:

```
console.log('foo');
```

I want them to be able to see the results of the `.log()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- click on that arrow next to **JavaScript**
- and as **FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS** select **No-Libary (Pure JS)**
- paste your **`console.log('foo');`** in JS box
- under **Resources** add **`https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js`**
- and run your script hitting that Play button

[image]

Comment: That shows it in the dev console, not in the HTML results.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm confused. Are you saying that you want to see the result of console.log on the HTML results?

Comment: @Rubén yes. The purpose of JSFiddle is to be a web-based javascript IDE.

Comment: For me, console.log does not work like this in jsfiddle it shows up in dev console.

Comment: @EvanCarroll To print out results to HTML results use document.write instead of console.log

Comment: Oh, I see now you're adding `https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js` into the mix in your last edit.

Comment: I don't think you should cut the other stuff out, and as `FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS select No-Libary (Pure JS)` (that's the default)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I am on chrome (v 67.0.3396.99 (oficial) (64-bit)). did you add https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js ?

Comment: @EvanCarroll `No-Libary (Pure JS)` wasnt deafult for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the console of your web browser.

If you are using Chrome for Windows press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

For other alternatives checkout [How to get console inside jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39130610/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was going crazy because my `console.log` wasn't outputting anything to Chrome's developer console.  Then I realized that I had left "Info" type levels unchecked.  As soon as I rechecked that, `console.log` informational output starting showing up in the console. :facepalm

[image]